# Is .NET assuming a WebException when the web server return a not allowed message?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

I'm developing a client on WP7 that supports streaming and the contents are on a Rails server.

When I call a valid stream, everything works great but when I call a not valid stream, the server catches a `WebException` with the message:

```
The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
```

This is kind of weird because if I do the same request on a browser (pe. google chrome) I get the following json message:

```
{ "success":false, "error_code": "stream_not_allowed","error_message": "Streaming is not allowed" }
```

Well, I want to retrieve the error_message to display it to the client.

The code I'm using is:

```
private static void DoRequest(string path, GenericServiceHelper helper) {
    var uri = new Uri(path);
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = "GET";
    helper.request = request;
    request.BeginGetResponse(HandleResponse, helper);
}

private static void HandleResponse(IAsyncResult ar) {
    var helper = (GenericServiceHelper)ar.AsyncState;
    HttpWebRequest originalRequest = helper.request;
    HttpWebResponse response;

    try {
        response = (HttpWebResponse)originalRequest.EndGetResponse(ar);
    }
    catch (WebException e) {
        // It fails here
    }

    // Do normal stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'll get a `WebException` for any non-success HTTP status code (which is pretty reasonable, IMO).

You can get the response within a `WebException` via the [`Response`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response.aspx) property:

```
catch (WebException e) {
    // You should check the status code etc to make sure you're not masking
    // real errors.
    response = e.Response;
}
```

Comment: The WebException is without a doubt the expected behavior, the NotFound Message on the exception when the StatusCode is a BadRequest is misleading. Either way, you're absolutely right. Thanks